# separator for print is not inserted

Tags: python, json

I need to insert a separator into the result, but it is not inserted

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
elements = soup.select('div.button.m')
for i in elements:
result = i.attrs['data']
print(result, sep=', ')
```

with code i get list of 'data' attributes without delimiter

```
{"a":{"url":"https://exapmle1.com","accountsOnly":"False"},"displayHints":"Both"} {"a":{"url":"https://exapmle2.com","accountsOnly":"False"},"displayHints":"Both"}
```

i get result without delimiter
I need to insert a separator into the result, but it is not inserted
like that:

```
{"a":{"url":"https://exapmle1.com","accountsOnly":"False"},"displayHints":"Both"}, {"a":{"url":"https://exapmle2.com","accountsOnly":"False"},"displayHints":"Both"}
```

if you add `end=','` , then commas are inserted, but I don't need a comma at the end (I want to import the result into json)

upd: or maybe there is an option to immediately wrap these lines in a JSON array, for example:

{"list":[{"a":{"url":"https://exapmle1.com","accountsOnly":"False"},"displayHints":"Both"}, {"a":{"url":"https://exapmle2.com","accountsOnly":"False"},"displayHints":"Both"}]}

Answer (score 0):

**sep** wasn't working because i placed it in a for loop... only **end** works in for loop

I found the answer, but now I don't know how to do my task(((

in print (result) I get a list of json array strings, which I then need to merge into one array, from which I need to get a data table.
to do this, put commas between the lines

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `result` is a list of strings, you need to spread / splat its contents using `*` when you pass it to print, so it sees the values individually and can insert the separator between the values:

```
> python -q
>>> print(*['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv'], sep='--')
asdf--qwer--zxcv
```

If you just pass in the list, it will print out the list as a single item, essentially calling the `__str__` method on the list object:

```
>python -q
>>> print(['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv'], sep='--')
['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv']
```

Comment: not quite right, result is a list of strings, where in each string there is a part of the json array that is constantly changing

if I put print(*[result],sep='--') , then there is a comma after each character in the result